# Need to Add Oracle Listener for Second NIC

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am currently running Oracle 11g on a Windows 2012 Environment.

I recently added another NIC to allow for failover, however I am not sure as to what to do with my listener.ora file and my tnsnames.ora file. Could someone offer guidance? For reference, the current IP I am using is 192.168.0.52 and the IP of the second NIC that I would like to add has the IP of 192.168.0.53.

Below is my listener.ora file:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.52)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\Administrator
```

Below is my tnsnames.ora file:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.52)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.52)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can specify multiple `ADDRESS` entries in the `listener.ora`:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.52)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.53)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

And in `tnsnames.ora`:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.52)(PORT = 1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.53)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

When I specify multiple addresses for listener, it listens on all interfaces listed. And when at least one address in tnsnames can be connected to -- it connects. I have 11g available for testing both on the client-side and on the server-side. I checked the documentation ([Multiple Address Lists in tnsnames.ora](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm#NETRF262/)) and it states that parameter `(FAILOVER=on)` can be specified in `tnsnames.ora` explicitly.